# MOSFET Triggers with Electrostatic Energy

Tags: mosfet, electrostatic

In the attached circuit with a 5V relay and a 30V load across it, I've noticed the FQP30N06L MOSFET triggers with even electrostatic energy (touching the gate). The difference between the circuit under test and this one is rather than a 10K pulldown I'm using a 2K pulldown. Is there a way to prevent electrostatic energy from triggering the MOSFET? Is it just a matter of the pulldown resistor value? The voltage coming into the gate is 3.3V -- the coil voltage is 5V. Any help would be greatly appreciated. GND and GNDA are attached to the 3.3 V circuit and the 5V circuit, respectively.

[image]

Comment: If the GNDs are different (GND and GNDA) it is not gonna work properly (hence touching it turns it on). For this to work you need both GNDs to be tied together (not sure how thats gonna affect the rest of your design. If its isolated you can use an optocoupler to keep isolation.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but: why do the grounds need to be tied together? What difference does that make exactly? As an additional detail -- the two grounds in question come into being because the supply starts at 5V and then I divide that down to 3.3V. The 3.3V goes into a development board I am using that has a pinout to ground. So, in a sense the two grounds are really from the same supply, just at different ends.

Comment: Shunt Gate  to Source with a  cap. <= 0.1uF

Comment: ... just don't touch the gate. After all, why would you want to and risk damaging it?

Comment: @jsinglet - It's not related to your question, but you said that (not shown on the schematic): "*the supply starts at 5V and then I divide that down to 3.3V. The 3.3V goes into a development board*".  Using a resistor voltage divider to create the 3.3V power rail for a development board (which is what I *think* you are describing) will create a comparatively unregulated 3.3V rail, potentially leading to other problems. You may want to investigate that further.

Comment: @SamGibson -- yes, you nailed this. I was troubleshooting this and hooskworks pointed this out and suggested an LDO. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend connecting R2 on the other side of R3 closer to the gate of the MOSFET. Your schematic also suggests that the pull-down resistor uses a different ground to the source of the MOSFET (GND and GNDA respectively); i would connecting the pull-down resistor as close a possible to the MOSFET between the gate and source terminals.

If you still have problems then, since you're driving something slow like a mechanical relay, you can add some capacitance between the gate and the source of the MOSFET so that more charge is required to raise the gate-source voltage to the threshold level. An alternative to this is to add a Schottky diode in parallel with R3 to give a low impedance pull-down path when the MOSFET is blocking. Vgs(th) for the MOSFET is quoted at 1 V so you don't *need* to use a Schottky diode but it'll give the solutiuon the best chance of working for you.

Comment: Another posted suggested the problem is that the grounds are different -- I have the 5V GND separated from the 3.3V GND. Is your suggestion to tie the grounds together and move the resistor up?

Comment: @jsinglet not quite, they should be the same ground too unless you have a good reason for separating them. The ground attached to the source of the MOSFET should be the same ground as is attached to R2 (the pull-down resistor). Additionally R2 should be physically close to the MOSFET and connected with a minimum trace length to the MOSFET gate and source terminals.

Comment: As an additional detail -- the two grounds in question come into being because the supply starts at 5V and then I divide that down to 3.3V. The 3.3V goes into a development board I am using that has a pinout to ground. So, in a sense the two grounds are really from the same supply, just at different ends.

Comment: Thanks @hooskworks -- that's very helpful. In general when would I want to keep the grounds separated? Is there ever a good reason? For example, I think it makes sense that I wouldn't want to connect to the ground of a high voltage load I am switching, but other than that, are there guidelines?

Comment: Also, in terms of the resistor value -- does 2k seem sufficient or should I really be thinking about 10k?

Comment: @jsinglet I'm assuming you're using non-isolated power supplies. So, one situation is where you have an isolated power supply for generating the gate drive voltage of the upper MOSFET in a half-bridge. In this case the ground is 'floating' and held at the same potential as the output node of the bridge-leg which will change between the positive and negative supply rails to the bridge-leg.

Comment: @jsinglet 1-2k for a 3.3V logic level MOSFET should be sufficient. If you were using a traditional power MOSFET with, for example, +15/-5V gate voltage on and off states and + 5 V Vgs(th) then i would be recommending something more like a 10k resistor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99618/discussion-between-jsinglet-and-hooskworks).